# When use Android fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to write a simple app which will look different depending on the screen size.

On a small screen it would have a list of items and after click it will display details. On a bigger screen it would have a list of items and details next to it.

My question is: should I use `fragments` to do such an app or just write different layouts and place them in `layout-large` or `layout-land` folders?

Comment: I will suggest use fragments.

Comment: you should use both. You cant provide a different layouts without using diffrent layouts like `layout-large` or `layout-land` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a new app I would always go with fragments, basically for future proofing your app. You may have a single list now, but later you may want to introduce a menu for selecting different types of lists for example. By using fragments, on a phone you can use two activities, one for selection, and the other for the list, but on a tablet in landscape mode you can place the selection and list side-by-side.

Coding for possible app enhancements and features now, saves you time and headaches later.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in both way , but the suggested solution is using fragment

check this out :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

and this :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use Fragments, since Fragments were created for that purpose, besides, if you make 2 layouts, you will have to do 2 completely diferent layouts and that'll mean that the activity would not handle that, at least not in an easy way, so try fragments to achieve that, the [official documentation example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is a case like yours, that would be enough to believe that the correct way to do it is with fragments.